# Passing multiple exogeneous variables into ARMA

Tags: python, statsmodels, forecast

just wanted to check if I am doing this correctly. I am trying to obtain a one-step ahead out-of-sample forecast in a model with multiple exogeneous variables. In particular, I want to confirm if the order in which you arrange the exogeneous variables in the array passed to `exog` parameter of `forecast()` must be the same as the order of the dataframe passed to the `exog` parameter of `ARMA`.

This is what I have implemented:

```
model=ARMA(training['Y'],order=(1,0),exog=training[['A','B','C']])
model_fit=model.fit()
model_fit.forecast(steps=1,exog=data[['A','B','C']].iloc[-1,:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, the order should be the same.